# Can I write the dates in Italian like "1º del Giugno e 12 del Luglio"?

Tags: grammar

Can I write the dates in Italian like this?

> Spero essere a Italia tra 1º del Giugno e 12 del Luglio.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are several problems with the sentence. First of all, the verb *sperare* needs a *di* in front of another verb. Second, with countries one uses *in* not *a*.

More to the point of the question, the usage of dates is wrong: one needs to use the article in front of the *day*, not the *month*. Moreover the *di* in front of the month is optional, and sounds very strange after *primo* (the only cases where in Italian we occasionally use the ordinal number for dates). So the sentence should be:

> Spero di essere in Italia tra il 1° giugno e il 12 luglio

A more natural version of the sentence would use *da / a* instead of *tra*

> Spero di essere in Italia dall'1 giugno al 12 luglio.

As a minor point, in Italian the names of the months are not capitalized.

Comment: Or, for the second version, _Spero di essere in Italia dal 1° giugno al 12 luglio_, if we want to follow, here too, the custom of writing the first day of a month as an ordinal number.

Comment: Maybe it is worth mentioning that, in the spoken language, you can hear also "*Spero di essere in Italia dal primo **di** giugno al dodici (**di**) luglio*" but I'd say in the *written* form we would use "*dal/dall' 1 giugno al 12 luglio*" regardless of how we will articulate it.

Comment: > Spero di essere in Italia dall'1 giugno al 12 luglio is wrong!! Errors is: `dall'` and missing: `fino al` The correct sentence is: > Spero di essere in Italia dal 1° Giugno fino al 12 Luglio. Explain:<br>
`dall'` is a called in italian grammar as **elisione**. <br>
The full words was `dallo/dalla` where the vocal `o/a` can be erased, and replaced with `apostrophe` `'` .<br><br>But **not in this case** becouse cannot be used before a number Than you need to ad `fino al` to express the date untill you will stay in Italy.

Comment: @RogerAI I'm not sure where you found that “dall’1 giugno” is wrong. The number is read “uno” and the elision is mandatory. One can object that many people would say “dal primo giugno”, but this is only personal preference not mandated by any “grammatical rule”.

Comment: Thank you for correcting the whole sentence, I am still a beginner.

Comment: @RogerAI, "*fino al*" is not wrong but it is not mandatory either; "*dal ... al ...*" is perfectly fine. It is instead wrong the statement that the apostrophe cannot be used before a number, as you can verify on the [enciclopedia dell'italiano Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/apostrofo-prontuario_%28Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano%29/) (see section 6, second paragraph: "*L’apostrofo si usa anche davanti ai numeri e nelle date: l’8 settembre ’43*").

Comment: While here, always on enciclopedia dell'italiano Treccani, you can see a short handbook on how to write a date in Italian: https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/date-prontuario_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/

Comment: For what concerns the use of "*dal... al...*" or "*tra*", I'd say the first version indicates the exact dates of arrival and departure (I will arrive on June, 1st and I will leave on July, 12th) while the second indicates a period during which I could arrive and leave (I am planning to arrive on June, 1st *or later* and to leave by July, 12th *or earlier*).